# posting to facebook app via php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm fairly new at facebook api and I need some help.

I have a website and I would like to update

a) an image and related text

to my facebook app. This is to be done automatically from my web-site using php script.
I managed to get the access token and post data but if I try to post the day after, the php script returns an error saying that the acces token is expired.

I have searched on many posts - but nothing seems to work to renew this access token.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need "offline_access" permission if I understand your problem correctly. 
Then re-newing is not needed. (needed only when not working anymore due user password change and such)

You can read about it here http://eagerfish.eu/using-facebook-off-line-access-to-post-on-users-wall/

But maybe it's not the best solution at moment because there will be changes in API in May 1, 2012. "offline_access" Permission will be removed. http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Thanks Janar.I have requested the offline_access and it still didn't work.It's so frustrating trying to do somenthing simple